# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort.......Sort function not working in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, jupyter-notebook, attr

```
new_list=("a","g","x","e","s","s")     #created a list 
a=new_list.sort()   #try to sort it
```

and error is:

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6eb33c65fab6> in <module>()
----> 1 a=new_list.sort()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I get this Attribute error. I've restarted my kernel and also tried it on sublime-text-CMD. I still get the same error

Comment: You have a `tuple`... this is a list `new_list=["a","g","x","e","s","s"] ` and `new_list.sort()` sorts inplace

Comment: The error message is telling you that's not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see here ["Tuples and Sequences"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) you can see that your data structure is a tuple.

You can see here ["More on Lists"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) that `sort()` is a function only for arrays.

You can use [sorted()](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-or-object-with-sorted-in-python/) to sort arrays or tuples

```
new_list=("a","g","x","e","s","s")   
a=sorted(new_list) # ['a', 'e', 'g', 's', 's', 'x']
```

Answer (score 2):

`new_list` is defined as a `tuple`. Make it as a `list` by enclosing it in square 
brackets

```
new_list=["a","g","x","e","s","s"]
new_list.sort()
print (new_list)
# ['a', 'e', 'g', 's', 's', 'x']
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

A tuple is a sequence of immutable Python objects so that means you cannot change their value. Maybe you intended to use sorted instead of sort ?

```
new_list=("a","g","x","e","s","s")

a = sorted(new_list)
```